# How should I ask my co-workers that I need a handshower in the toilet?

Tags: culture

I live in Karachi, Pakistan and I have got a job offer from Dallas, Texas, USA. I am likely to move their soon. While researching the cultural difference I realized that a bidet is not usually used in USA and people prefer just the toilet paper. How should I ask my co-workers to install a handshower inside the toilet?

Comment: Another way around is I ask them to place a vessel inside the toilet or buy it myself and place it. But I will have to tell them why I am doing so.

Comment: Why not just use toilet paper? It's not a hard transition (speaking from experience), and you'll find a lot of American homes, public stalls, etc. don't have a bidet either. You won't be able to escape using it at some point.

Comment: Even if you are willing to pay the cost you should get permission from your boss.

Comment: Is there any way you could solve this yourself -- hand,-pumped squit bottle with a hose, perhaps? Or flushable wet-wipes? Can you find others from your culture and ask them how they manage? (Being both American and male, I have no experience with bidets.) Management would have to pay for plumbing changes and any additional cleaning costs,so @PhilipKendall is correct that HR would be the place to ask.

Comment: @M.Kinz I think such a request would be met the same way anywhere in the US; it's likely to be ignored, as it isn't customary here.

Comment: I don't really understand why this is being downvoted - it seems on topic enough to me?

Comment: actually in this way the west is less advanced. I am a westerner myself and I have switched to water, its much more better.

Comment: @Rigolletto - Why is it called a handshower?

Comment: How on earth is this question opinion-based? Please remember that **close votes are not super-downvotes.** And while you're free to vote up and down for any reason you like, like @enderland I'm having trouble determining that reason for this post.

Comment: it's just called a "handshower" because it is, literally, just a small handshower that hangs on the wall beside the toilet, ie at about the height of the seat.  it's literally just the same as a handshower in a shower, except it hangs at toilet-height on the wall beside the toilet.  (they are also useful for generally cleaning the floor/whatever.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a portable bidet like one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=portable%20bidet&oq=portablebidet&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.6393j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8).  I keep one on my boat for overnight trips.

Your coworkers never need to know.

I worked with a Pakistani in my last job,  I'm reasonably certain this is what he did judging by the parcel he carried into the toilet occasionally (presumably when #2 was imminent).  He carried a prayer rug in a similar parcel when he used an empty office for his prayers.

Answer (score 37):

If this is a medical condition which means that you need this facility, then you bring it up with your manager or HR, not with your co-workers.

If it's actually not a need but a personal preference, then I'd strongly suggest that you don't bring it up at all. You made the decision to move to a different culture, so a lot of the burden is on you to adapt to that new culture, not on that culture to adapt to you. Otherwise you're saying "I'm special. You all need to change your life because I won't change mine.", and that's not a way to fit in to a new culture, either at work or outside work.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer. The "you all need to change your life" seems somewhat overstated though. It's not as though everyone else will have to stop using toilet paper.

Comment: I agree with this answer as well. I am a French person living in the US. I am used to bidets in France. And even thought I think that all Americans are super unclean because they don't use bidets, I would never think to ask for that at my workplace. That being said, if you have a gym at work, or if some employees bike to work, it wouldn't be unusual to have a couple of showers in the bathrooms (especially in Texas where it is so hot outside). Or if you work at Google, it wouldn't be unusual of them to have a few Japanese-like bathrooms, which can fulfill the same function and more.

Comment: Here are pictures of one of those at Google. http://sfist.com/2008/06/26/behold_google_offices_toilets.php#photo-2